# React Native Error Advice - The development server returned response error code:500

Tags: android-emulator, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am using React Native and encountered the following error on my android emulator

[image]

I am new to React Native and was coding in App.js. I watched a tutorial online on how to use react-navigation so I was following it and created a homestack.js file. My app.js file was still working perfectly fine at this point.

I added code to homestack.js and then imported it to my app.js file but that's when this error popped up. This error was not resolved when I commented out all of the code on homestack.js nor when I commented out the import on my app.js file.

I followed the instructions on the error (clear watchman, delete node modules, yarn install, yarn reset cache) but this also did not resolve the issue.

**The fix:**
Since none of the above fixed the issue, I removed the homestack.js file from my root folder completely which then fixed the issue. What I did not expect however was that when I put the homestack.js file back into the root folder to see what would happen, the app ran again fine with no issues. It was as if the error never happened.

I guess my question is, what was the actual issue here? Why did taking the file out of the folder and then placing it back in fix the issue? I ran 'npx react-native run-android' after every step of the above fix process so the issue was not because the emulator was running an old version.

Answer (score 0):

Following this error, You have imported react-navigation-stack without install the package. You can install the packge 
`yarn add react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view react-native-safe-area-context`

or 
`npm install react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view react-native-safe-area-context`

To know more `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-stack` 
After install the package clean project by executing command `cd android && gradlew clean`, then debug your project.

Comment: I have already installed the packages you said. I have also run gradlew clean but still receive this same error. The issue is not the package installation. I just seen this error again today but no idea how to fix.